Numerical relations in a parabola
Today I found some free time and I had the idea of adding as many theorems as possible concerning the parabola, but provided that these theorems indicate a certain algebraic relationship in the parabola.
This equation may be connecting blind side lengths, certain areas, or angle measurements, no problem.
I will put the results that I have compiled in an answer and I hope you will help me expand it

What is your question? Perhaps pose a question and add your images as an answer

This is not a question.

I want to expand the list with more theorems related to parabolas that refer to an algebraic equation that is realized. @lhf

Can you refine the question and suggest another title? Note that I am not looking for the properties of parallelism or falling on the same line or the properties of the confluence of a set of lines at one point, but for the properties that connect some elements to each other through an algebraic equation @SeanRoberson

You should mention that you're compiling your list in an answer (for those of us who don't immediately scroll down after reading a question). Also, in light of the unfortunate miss in your recent question, you should indicate which of your results are merely conjectures and which have been proven. ... Interesting stuff, as always! :)

My last question was based on approximate experiment, unlike my usual method of discovering results, which relies on Euclidean geometry accurately. But okay, I'll do it.

Well, many of your questions featuring your discoveries ask for proof, so it's helpful (at least to me) to know which results already have them. (As you know, an accurate construction, even when computer-assisted, doesn't constitute a proof. There's no telling how many under-the-hood numerical errors the software may be making.) ... Thanks!

When I post something like a "list of rules" it is a final result, and I am pretty sure it is correct, I don't want to harm society, and when I put my last question I wrote in the text of the question that I could not construct the Euclidean geometry of drawing as a warning, I will try to be more careful in the future and hope to regain the trust of society.

No trust issues here. :) I wasn't being critical, merely suggesting a few improvements in the interest of making your question as comprehensive as possible. (BTW: I applaud that you assign proper credit to your friend. Similar credit for the results you "collected from the internet" would be appreciated, for the sake of completeness, if you can recall the sources.) ... Very best regards. (I'll leave you alone now. ;)

I've compiled 40 theorems and numbered them for easier navigation








My discoveries are the same numbers: 8,9,10,16,19,20,21,22,25,26,27,29,30,35,36,37,38,39,40 I've proven them all except for the numbers 16,21,36,37,38,39 and 40 I haven't fixed them yet
The numbers 24,31,32,33 are discovered by a friend of mine named Fawaz.
As for the rest of the numbers I collected from the Internet
